# Prefix in word 'elongation'

Tags: prefixes

I just wondered if there is a ***e-*** prefix.

For example to form the word ***elongation*** having as root the word ***long*** .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a prefix although in its assimilated form because of the following consonant ***l***.

The actual prefix is

**ex-**

> word-forming element, in English meaning usually "*out of, from*," but also "*upwards, completely, deprive of, without*," and "*former*;" from Latin ***ex*** "out of, from within; from which time, since; according to; in regard to," from PIE ****eghs*** "out" (source also of Gaulish ***ex***-, Old Irish ess-, Old Church Slavonic izu, Russian iz). In some cases also from Greek cognate ***ex***, ***ek***. PIE *eghs had comparative form *eks-tero and superlative *eks-t(e)r-emo-. ***Often reduced to e- before -b-, -d-, -g-, consonantal -i-, -l-, -m-, -n-, -v- (as in elude, emerge, evaporate, etc.).***

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ex-#etymonline_v_14008)

About *elongation*, the [same dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/elongation) says:

> c. 1400, *elongacioun*, in astronomy, "*angular distance of a planet from the sun as it appears from the earth*;" early 15c., "*extension, spreading*," from Medieval Latin ***elongationem*** (nominative elongatio), noun of action from past-participle stem of Late Latin *elongare* "remove to a distance," f*rom assimilated form of Latin* ***ex*** "*out*"  + ***longus*** "*long*".